# PHP explode text to multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, explode

I wanna explode this text to **three dimensional array**:

```
Q 11 21 21 ( 40 44 23 ! 24 ! ! Q ! 32 22 48 18 23 49 ! ! ! ! 24 23 Q ! 19 23 06 49 29 15 22 ! ! ! Q ! 20 ( 23 23 ( 40 ! ! ! ! Q ! 21 06 ! 22 22 22 02 ! ! !


Q ! ( 40 05 33 ! 05 ! ! ! ! Q ! 49 49 05 20 20 49 ! ! ! Q ! ! 05 34 ( 40 ( ( 1 Q ! ! 46 46 46 46 46 46 ! ! ! Q ( 46 07 20 12 05 33 ! ! ! !
```

This is timetable is in *text form*. The following are the conditions that determine each value in the array:

1. new row = next time table;
2. Q = new day;
3. space = next hour
4. ! = free hour,
5. ( = duplicit hour

And I want it like this:
**array[timetable][day][hour]**

How can I do that? Is there choice do it by PHP explode function?

Comment: Satisfy my own curiosity: is that format part of a standard?

Comment: you will have to explain better to get any answers..

Comment: What prevents you from just coding the parser for that? I mean you already formulated the format, what prevents you to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without really understanding how your strings work; This code should do the job.

```
$timetables = explode("\n", $source);

foreach($timetables as $tablekey => $days)
{
    $timetables[$tablekey] = explode('Q', $days);

    foreach($timetables[$tablekey] as $daykey => $hours)
        $timetables[$tablekey][$daykey] = explode(' ', $hours)
}

print_r($timetables, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

What a nice format! I think I still don't get it, but I'll try answering anyway...

1. use `explode` with "\n" and you'll get an array of timetables
2. for each element of this array, replace it with an `explode` of itself with 'Q' and you'll have a 2-dimensional array
3. for each element of each element of this array, replace the element with an `explode` of itself with ' '

Try to do this and if you're having trouble, edit your question with the code you'd come up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = //...
$x = explode("\n", $x);
foreach($x as $k => $v) {
  $x[$k] = explode("Q", $x[$k]);
  foreach($x[$k] as $kk => $vv) {
    $x[$k][$kk] = explode(" ", $x[$k][$kk]);
  }
}
```

With [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) I think you wiil get somewhat nicer code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive function that takes an array of delimiters:

```
function multi_explode($delimiters, $val) {
    $delimiter = array_shift($delimiters);
    if (!empty($delimiter)) {
        $val = explode($delimiter, $val);
        foreach($val as $key => $valval) {
            $val[$key] = multi_explode($delimiters, $valval);
        }
    }
    return $val;
}
```